# Why is my query for clickhouse cluster so slow?

Tags: clickhouse

When I use clickhouse-go/v2 to connect the clickhouse (22.1.3.7), I encountered such some problems:

```
I use clickhouse.OpenDB,and urls is ["ip1:9000","ip2:9000","ip3:9000","ip4:9000"]
DialTimeout is 10 s,idle conn is 50,maxopenconn is 1000,maxlifetime is 1 hour
```

Background: The log volume of the business system is 30M per second
The log format is as follows:
time level type traceid parentid spanid service instance ip msg

level has only five values

Type has 10 values

traceid/parentid/spanid are the three values ​​to be used in the call chain

There are about 1000 services, and instance is a sub-item of service. If service=svr1, the value of instance is svr-0, svr-1, svr-2, and the number is from 1-100

When building the table, I partition by day

The order by fields are as follows: time, type, level, service, instance, traceid

There are several problems now:

The first problem is that the cluster query is super slow:
For a single clickhouse, the writing and querying speeds are within an acceptable range, but when connected to a cluster, there is no problem writing, but the response is extremely slow when querying.
Check the condition separately: where type='ingress' and time>='2023-07-07 10:00:00' and time <=2023-07-07 11:00:00, the difference is 1 hour
Under the premise of one concurrency, when the amount of data is 8G, it takes about 500ms
But in the case of 5 concurrency, the time-consuming directly soars to 2s, and when the concurrency is increased to 10, 20, the time-consuming directly soars to 10+s
Do not you know why?

The second question is: is there a problem with such a design table? Does the order by field need to be adjusted, the smaller the field, the higher the front?

The third question: Is the division by day too rough? Is it necessary to adjust it to division by hour?

how is my order by?
how do i create the table?

Comment: What are you using for a primary key? Is filtering by "type" and "time" your highest priority for query performance? If so, then I would put "type" first and "time" second

Comment: primary key is the same as the order by fields.time is a required filter。 type, service, and traceid are all optional filters, but they will be used in different query scenarios，so I don't known where is the problem? zookeeper cluster is deployed on the same vms with clickhouse cluster,will it affect？